# Displaying Multiple Tables in a Page in Jasper Reports using ireports/Jasper Assistant

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a report to be printed or exported to PDF format. I'm using jasper reports and jasper assistant/ireports.

I have 8 individual pages to be exported. so I prepared 8 separate design files.

In that, 6 pages are having more static text and mere direct mapping and the remaining two pages consists of tabular data.

one page contains a huge table so I filled it directly with by keeping a single table in the detail band.

Now the problem is that one page has more than 5 small tables (two or four columns).

Is it possible to have more that one table per page in jasper reports?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the number of columns in your main report.

This will cause the tables to over flow to the second column when they hit the end of the page.

It can be set in the root node of your report like bellow.

```
    <jasperReport columnCount="2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" 
columnWidth="275" columnSpacing="5">
```

If you are using iReport it can be set in the main reports properties in the column section.